# I'm trying to select rows in a dependent table based on a date calculation with the join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Dependent table `events`

```
class Events < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event

scope :scheduled_clean, -> {
 joins(:event)
   .where(self.arel_table[:created_at].lt(Date.today - Event.arel_table[:days_to_keep] )
}
```

The result: TypeError(expected numeric)

How can `Date.today` be expressed to make the calculation work?

Can the calculation even be done without resorting to raw sql?

Comment: The mysql to achieve the objective is:
  select b.*, e.name 
  from blog_events b, events e 
  where b.event_id = e.id and b.created_at < DATE_SUB(now(), interval e.days_to_keep day);

Answer (score 0):

After much fruitless research, thought I'd give chatGPT a go to solve the problem.

I posed the following question. It's a bit loose and not quite right but... it's my first attempt.

*write a ruby activerecord scope to select all rows from the
blog_events table joined with the event table to satisfy the
constraint that the blog_event rows are less than the current date -
event.days_to_keep compared to event.created_at*

This is the chatGPT answer verbatim:

> Here's an example ActiveRecord scope that should select all rows from
> the blog_events table joined with the events table to satisfy the
> constraint that the blog_event rows are less than the current date
> minus event.days_to_keep compared to event.created_at:
>
> ```
> class BlogEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
>   belongs_to :event
>
>   scope :within_days_to_keep, -> {
>     joins(:event)
>       .where("blog_events.created_at >= events.created_at - INTERVAL events.days_to_keep DAY")
>   }
> end
> ```
>
> This scope joins the blog_events and events tables and uses the where
> method to filter the results based on the created_at value in the
> blog_events table. The DateTime.now method gets the current date and
> time, and the Event.arel_table[:days_to_keep].days expression
> generates an Arel expression to subtract event.days_to_keep days from
> the current date. This Arel expression is then interpolated into the
> SQL query using a question mark placeholder, which is filled in with
> the Arel expression's value.
>
> Note that this assumes that you're using a database that supports the
> days method on Arel expressions, such as PostgreSQL. If you're using a
> different database, you may need to modify the query accordingly.

So, it got the test around the wrong way and added a bit because of my loose description. Made a few corrections and the problem solved, albeit using similar raw SQL as per my comment. Fixed the scope name. Amazing nevertheless. Solution isn't arel based as I'd prefer but solves the problem.

```
scope :scheduled_clean, -> {
    joins(:event)
      .where("blog_events.created_at < now() - INTERVAL events.days_to_keep DAY")
  }
```

Comment: If you ask a separate question about how to convert that query into Arel I'm sure we can help you.